# How to add JsonPropertyName to inherited properties?

Tags: c#, inheritance, system.text.json

How do I deserialize json to my class that is inheriting from base class but properties in base class do not match json? I cant's control base class. For example:

```json
{
  "prop1": "Value1",
  "prop2": "Value2"
}
```

I want to deserialize above to `MyClass`:

```cs
public class MyClass : Base
{
    [JsonPropertyName("prop2")]
    public string? Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Base // I do not own this
{
  public string? Property1 { get; init; }
}
```

Should I override Base properties and decorate them?

Comment: Do you have control over the base class too? Can you make changes to that?

Comment: @Pawel your code can not be event compiled. Pls post the right one

Comment: @Pawel { get; init; } "{ get; init; }" how it is init?

Comment: @Serge I'm not sure what do you mean. `Property1` is init-only.

Comment: @Pawel Yes, but where is the code to init it?  Does it have the special constructor?

Comment: Do you need to serialize, or only deserialize?

Comment: @Serge Without explicit constructor I'd assume init-only properties can only be initialized with object initializers. For example `MyClass a = new() { Property1 = "v1" };`

Comment: @dbc Only deserialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use same property name then you should hide base class property with `new` keyword and mark it with `JsonPropertyName` attribute:

```
public class MyClass : Base
{
    [JsonPropertyName("prop2")]
    public string? MyProperty2 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("prop1")]
    public new string? Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Also you can implement [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter) for type instead to find a specific properties in JSON and map them to object properties. This will keep your model clean from a specific of JSON model.

```
public class MyClassJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyClass>
{
    public override MyClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        var rootElement = jsonDocument.RootElement;
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.Property1 = rootElement.GetProperty("prop1").GetString();
        myClass.Property2 = rootElement.GetProperty("prop2").GetString();
        return myClass;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // imlement logic here if needed
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyClassJsonConverter))]
public class MyClass : Base
{
    public string? MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Also here is a big detailed article ["How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to) with examples for converters, converter factory, error handling converters registration and other aspects about converters for JSON serialization.

For example you don't have to use `JsonConverterAttribute` and call Deserialize with explicitly specified converters:

```
public class MyClass : Base
{
    public string? MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    Converters =
    {
        new MyClassJsonConverter()
    }
};

var myClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonString, deserializeOptions)!;
```

Comment: _"with new keyword and mark it with JsonPropertyName attribute:"_ - but better not to do it =)

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, I agree that it is bad practice and also in general the model should be independent of the storage format. Then there is a better and complex solution with JsonConverter :)

Comment: a class can't inherit from a record

Comment: @Serge I corrected my question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @vadim-martynov Thank you, I found "hide with `new` keyword" approach work best in my case. I had to modify implementation a bit because base class was doing some logic with `Property1` on initialization, and to have base value not null I did this: `[JsonPropertyName("prop1")] public new string? Property1 { get => base.Property1; init => base.Property1 = value; }`. Why do you think this a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom JsonConverter from @VadimMartynov, but more simple way is to add a  property

```
public class MyClass : Base
{
    [JsonPropertyName("prop2")]
    public string? Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("prop1")]
    public new string? Property1
    {
        get { return base.Property1; }
        init { base.Property1 = value; }
    }
}
```

but I recommend you to start to use Newtonsoft.Json. This code would be much more clear

```
public class MyClass : Base
{
    [JsonProperty("prop2")]
    public string? Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyClass(string? prop1)
    {
        Property1 = prop1;
    }
}
```